# RESOLVED. When show MapView inside AlertDialog, dialog buttons disappeared

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-mapview

I'm using AlertDialog with several custom layouts and I have a strange problem with one of them:
I'm trying to use google map view in AlertDialog:

```
   // this common code used for all alert dialogs
   // I have different dialogIds so specific code is used where needed.

   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity);
   final View view = viewInitializer.getView(dialogId, mActivity);
   builder.setMessage(message);
   builder.setCancelable(false);
   builder.setView(view)
   // Add action buttons
     .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
           // do something....
        }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        }
   });

   Dialog dialog = builder.create();
   builder.show();

   .......
   // map view specific code
   final MapView mapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
   MapsInitializer.initialize(mActivity);

   mapView.onCreate(dialog.onSaveInstanceState());
   mapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately
   mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        final GoogleMap gmap = googleMap;
        gmap.setMinZoomPreference(12);
        LatLng ny = new LatLng(42.6021767,23.4674597);
        gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ny));
      }
   });
   ...........
```

----------- layout templates: ------------
    // one of the dialogs that are ok.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/seatsCountPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="top"/>

</LinearLayout>

// the dialog with map view that are not ok.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/pointPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/points"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/pointPicker2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/points"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0pt"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="top"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Other dialogs are ok
Dialog with map is without buttons. I've tried to set small size and different weights of the mapview because I thought the buttons are behind the map. but still no buttons.

Any idea ?

[RESOLVED]
Hmm, Strange. If I remove "layout_weight" and use only fixed value for height it's ok. Now I just have to find how to deal with different screen sizes.

Screenshots are attached - dialogs that are ok and map view dialog without buttons.[image]

Comment: did you tried to set to `android:layout_height` of mapView some value?

Comment: yes. I've tried set height an width.   no matter if mapview is big or small there are no buttons.

Comment: Strange. If I use fixed height and remove weight it's ok.  But If I want to use weight it's not ok.
Anyway. My problem is 50% solved :) Thanks Vadim.
Now I have to deal with different screen sizes. because I', not sure this fixed height is 100% ok.

Comment: you can try to make your root as constraintlayout and not linnear, it responsive if you use it correct.

Comment: or make buttons not from default like (setPositiveButton), you can create buttons in your layout and set onClick in code.